# Firebase list child in listview

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to Firebase, and I need to show a child info on a listview. It adds the data, but it does not show on listview and the app crashes. No error is shown on log, but on firebase crash I have this error:

```
Exception com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.util.HashMap to String
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzamy.zzcg ()
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzamy.zzb ()
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzamy.zza ()
com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue ()
br.com.imobapp.CorretorFragment$1.onChildAdded (CorretorFragment.java:58)
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaip.zza ()
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzakp.zzcxi ()
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaks$1.run ()
android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:739)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:145)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5832)
```

My data is like this (Sorry, can't post pics since my account is new, only the link):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZHFC.jpg

My model is:

```
import com.google.firebase.database.IgnoreExtraProperties;

@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class ModelCorretor {
    private String CorNome;
    private String CorCreci;


    public ModelCorretor(){

    };

    public ModelCorretor(String CorNome, String CorCreci){

        this.CorNome = CorNome;
        this.CorCreci = CorCreci;

    };

    public String getCorNome() {
        return CorNome;
    }

    public void setCorNome(String corNome) {
        CorNome = corNome;
    }

    public String getCorCreci() {
        return CorCreci;
    }

    public void setCorCreci(String corCreci) {
        CorCreci = corCreci;
    }
}
```

And my fragment for showing it on listview:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;


public class CorretorFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    public CorretorFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    ImageButton btAddCor, btSearchCor;
    ListView lvCorretor;
    DatabaseReference dref;
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_corretor, container, false);
        btAddCor =(ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.btAddCor);
        btAddCor.setOnClickListener(this);
        btSearchCor =(ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.btSearchCor);
        btSearchCor.setOnClickListener(this);
        lvCorretor = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.lvCorretor);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, list);
        lvCorretor.setAdapter(adapter);

        dref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Corretores");
        dref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            // Read from the database
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                list.add(value);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                // This method is called once with the initial value and again
                // whenever data at this location is updated.
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                list.remove(value);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError  error) {
                // Failed to read value
                Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
            }
        });




        return view;
    }


        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
        MainActivity activity = (MainActivity)getActivity();
            switch(view.getId()){

                case R.id.btAddCor:
                    activity.chamaAddCor();
                    break;
                case R.id.btSearchCor:
                    activity.chamaSearchCor();
                    break;
                default: throw new RuntimeException("unreachable");

            }
        }
}
```

If any more code is needed or if I did something wrong in the question, please let me know.
I have an idea that I have to set a child for it to show, like I did in `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Corretores");` but I tried a lot and have no clue how to do it on the `onChildAdded`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
 String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
```

You shouldn't be getting a String object, you should be getting the model for the object you want. You have a model for your Corretor, so you do:

```
 ModelCorretor value = dataSnapshot.getValue(ModelCorretor.class);
```

`getValue` returns a hashmap and you are assigning it to a string, which is why you are getting that error. Firebase is great in that it will build that object for you by just inserting the `ModelCorretor` as a parameter in the `getValue` method.

Comment: Thank you, it works. But now it gives another error. In the list.add(value) it says add (java.lang.String) in Array List cannot be applied to br.com.imobapp.ModelCorretor. How do I modify it to an object?

Comment: I've fixed it, I forgot to declare  ArrayList<ModelCorretor> list = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayAdapter<ModelCorretor> adapter;